# ROSTutorialsWritingPublisherSubscriber(c++)

Tags: ros, tutorial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have some questions when I go through this tutorial. When I finished 1.1 and 1.2, then in the 1.3 I try to change the content in the `CMakeLists.txt`, then it's supposed to create two executables, talker and listener, which by default will go into package directory of your devel space, located by default at `~/catkin_ws/devel/lib/share/`, however there isn't share in lib and there are no executables.

Hello everyone, after I asked for some people's help finally I solved this problem, first of all, something was wrong in the tutorial that is there does not exist `~/catkin_ws/devel/lib/share/`, instead we have `devel/lib/beginner_tutorials` (which is my package name). But before we get two executable in beginner_tutorials, the last thing we should do is to change some content in `Cmakelists.txt`, the `Cmakelists.txt` in the tutorial also has something wrong.
In the tutorial:

```
# %Tag(FULLTEXT)%
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(beginner_tutorials)

## Find catkin and any catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp rospy std_msgs genmsg)

## Declare ROS messages and services
add_message_files(FILES Num.msg)
add_service_files(FILES AddTwoInts.srv)

## Generate added messages and services
generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES std_msgs)

## Declare a catkin package
catkin_package()

## Build talker and listener
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(talker src/talker.cpp)
target_link_libraries(talker ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(talker beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp)

add_executable(listener src/listener.cpp)
target_link_libraries(listener ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(listener beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp)

# %EndTag(FULLTEXT)%
```

we should comment out

```
add_message_files(FILES Num.msg)
add_service_files(FILES AddTwoInts.srv)
```

this two line, which means it should be like this: #add.......

if you don't do this, you will find something wrong when you try to use catkin_make

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202393/rostutorialswritingpublishersubscriber(c++)/) by [YunfeiLu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21559/yunfeilu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2015-02-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kokirits](https://answers.ros.org/users/21162/kokirits/) on 2015-02-04**:
Could you add the CMakeLists.txt and the console output from catkin_make in your post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Without the actual console output from your `catkin_make` invocation (and the error message), the below is just a guess, but:

> [..]
> we should comment out
>
> ```
> add_message_files(FILES Num.msg)
> add_service_files(FILES AddTwoInts.srv)
> ```
>
> this two line, which means it should be like this: #add.......
>
> if you don't do this, you will find something wrong when you try to use catkin_make

I don't think your suggested changes are needed.

Do you still have the `Num.msg` and `AddTwoInts.srv` files in the `msg` and `srv` subdirectories of your package from the [Creating a ROS msg and srv](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv) tutorial? If you don't, then `catkin_make` will probably fail, as it cannot find those files.

The [Writing a Simple Publisher and Subscriber (C++)](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29) tutorial explicitly states (under [1.3 Building your nodes](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29#roscpp_tutorials.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-WritingPublisherSubscriber.Building_your_nodes-1)) (emphasis mine):

> The generated [CMakeLists.txt](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt) should look like this (**with modifications from the Creating Msgs and Srvs tutorial** and unused comments and examples removed)

And then shows the lines you added to your OP.

If `msg/Num.msg` and `srv/AddTwoInts.srv` are no longer in your package, then you should comment the lines you suggested. But in general they should be there, as the next tutorials ([Writing a Simple Service and Client (C++)](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28c%2B%2B%29) fi) depend on them.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0